# How to connect to nREPL from Proto REPL in Atom without having to enter host and port manually?

Tags: atom-editor, clojurescript, proto-repl

Currently, I have a ClojureScript nREPL which runs on `3333`. I want to connect to the nREPL from Atom using Proto REPL. I am now using the `cmd+shift+p > nREPL connect > enter host and port`. After which I run the atom init script:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'nrepl:connect', ->
  protoRepl.executeCode("(shadow.cljs.devtools.api/node-repl)")
```

Is there a way to open the Proto REPL and connect directly from the init script without having to enter the host and port manually? I am starting the watch using

```
yarn shadow-cljs watch app
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `.nrepl-port` file with the content of `3333`?  This is the way `lein repl` communicates the port - e.g. `vim-fireplace` uses that.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks, that simplifies the process a bit, though it would be helpful if I can launch the whole Proto REPL with the env with a single atom command.